# Dealing with unmapped property in Doctrine Repository

Tags: php, symfony, events, doctrine

I have an entity `BlogPost` which has a field `status`. This status is dependent on some data from an external API. For dealing with this, i implemented a postLoad listener which is set up the status after the entity was loaded.

The problem now is, i want to filter by this status.

In my repository i would usually write a method which is something like `getBlogPostByStatusXY()`.

But this will not work now since this data is nothing saved as a real property in my database ...

Does anybody has a smart idea how to deal with this?

If i am not able to avoid saving the status to the database ... how can i deal with it, without doing unnecessary stressing my API (for calculating the status).

I thought about doing something like "Whenever something is touched from this repository, initially update the status of all BlogPosts and save it back to the database" ... This would be one API call and comparative cheap, but i cant find an event for doing this ... all events are based on a single entity but not for touching the repository. Saving it during a single-entity-event (e.g. postLoad) will doing the api call unnecessarily for all entities ...

Does somebody has another idea?

Thanks

Comment: where are you ususally calling your respository function? in controllers or services. so why not simply creating a service which does it?

Comment: Any webhook / push notification support in the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some question you may want to get answers to:

1. Can you ask your API for multiple statuses at the same time, or you need to do it one by one?

This is critically important if your need to make 50 HTTP requests, or just a single one.

2. What is the average round trip time of your API request?

Kinda related to question #1, but still...

3. How many object do your fetch from DB per request? Or to rephrase, how many objects are being candidates for `status` updates per request?

`Doctrine` is very clever when it comes to need to issue an `UPDATE` query, but not so much if you use your own DQL.

Do any of above answers hint towards a bottleneck?

Thinking about it, two ideas come to mind:

### IDEA #1: Transient in-memory cached `status`:

First request:

1. fetch entries from DB
2. check local in-memory cache and resolve missing statuses
3. put statuses in timeout cache (e.g. ttl=5min or more), each in separate key (e.g. `BlogPost-status-<id>`)
4. in PHP, filter out your entities based on `status` field

Next request:

1. fetch entries from DB
2. check local in-memory cache and resolve missing statuses
3. update your in-memory cache
4. in PHP, filter out your entities based on `status` field

### IDEA #2: Persistent `status`

First request:

1. fetch entries from DB
2. check local in-memory cache and resolve missing statuses
3. write to DB column the results

Next request:

1. fetch entries from DB by applying `status` filter
2. check local in-memory cache and resolve missing statuses (PROBLEM: you filtered out only some entities , so what about other entities?)
3. write to DB columns the result of your API (if any)

There may be some other relevant approaches.

Hope this helps a bit...